# How resources of the servers are calculated in virtualiuzation?

Tags: server, virtualization, vmware, kvm-virtualization

I have a dedicated server with the following specifications:

20 core cpu
256GB RAM

I have four guest servers hosted on this dedicated server. with the specifications below:

```
server1 4 cores and 30GB RAM
server2 4 cores and 30GB RAM
server3 4 cores and 30GB RAM
server1 10 cores and 164GB RAM
```

now when I am checking the RAM consumption I see the following outcomes:

Server1 :

```
root@server1:~# free -lh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           28G        15G        13G       6.1M       179M       3.9G
Low:           28G        15G        13G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:        11G        17G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Server2:

```
root@Server2:~# free -lh
                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:           28G        28G       213M       852K       149M       2.1G
    Low:           28G        28G       213M
    High:           0B         0B         0B
    -/+ buffers/cache:        26G       2.4G
    Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Server3:

```
root@server3:~# free -lh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           28G        27G       1.2G       852K       131M       1.1G
Low:           28G        27G       1.2G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:        26G       2.5G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Server4:

```
nashwan@BigData:~$ free  -lh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          144G       1.4G       142G       6.9M       128M       621M
Low:          144G       1.4G       142G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:       696M       143G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

The ironies is that when I am checking the host server itself, it gives the following results:

```
root@Host:~# free -lh
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          251G        23G       227G        71M       654M       681M
Low:          251G        23G       227G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:        22G       229G
Swap:         1.0G         0B       1.0G
```

can anyone help me out how this has been calculated, or actually how this could be correct!

Comment: Hi, As far as I know the definition of `cached`, `buffer` and `free` is different in unix systems from our general idea.

Comment: Ok so what do you suggest me to check the amount of RAM consumed by each VM. By the way even graphical interface of the hypervisor shows same amount of consumed RAM.

Comment: Just do `free-m` and only focus on `used` and `available` column.

Comment: I got same result.

Comment: sorry cannot help you. i see a different output with 16.04.